# Sorting Strings in Rails using Order

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I Have a model "Msg" and it has a content as a string and a username as a string as well

at the moment all my Msgs have their content Lorem Ipsumed and I'd like to sort them out

I'm trying to do something like

```
Msg.all(:order => "content DESC")
```

but it will not sort the strings for me..

Is there anyway to sort the strings in one line to get all of the Msgs (or the actual strings)

Thanks

Comment: What does that mean: It will not sort the strings for me? It sorts the msg-objects (descending) by the content of the objects. Or do you want to sort by usernames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure to understand the question.

```
Msg.all(:order => "content DESC")
```

retrieves all messages ordered by its content. Consequently, mapping its content attributes returns all the strings properly sorted

```
Msg.all(:order => "content DESC").map(&:content)
```

Comment: Thanks. This still won't sort it for me (it does help me do other things). if I add .sort it gives it to me sorted.

Comment: It should. Msg.all(:order => "content DESC") return an array of messages ordered by the content, so mapind the content attribute returns the array of sortered contents. Try Msg.all(:order => "content ASC").map(&:content)